# jquery animated buttons that just wont behave

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggleclass

Ok I have a inline list of buttons.

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="home"><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
   <li class="contact"><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
   <li class="about"><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>

.home{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
background-image:url(../img/menu/single_line.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:34px;
width:134px;
}
.home_hover{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
background-image:url(../img/menu/single_line_over.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:70px;
width:134px;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#nav .home").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("home_hover").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("home_hover").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Each menu item has a background image, and then when its hovered the background image is replaced by a taller image.  Ultimately I am trying to build a simple menu where on mouseover the menu item appears to slide up.  But in reality Jquery can animate the toggleClass with slideToggle.  The problem is that this current code doesn't behave right.

It jumps up and down, because the text is moving.  I am pretty new to Jquery so any help is greatly appreciated.  I also loaded this up at http://gasworks.ravennainteractive.com/result/

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qn7XT/)):

CSS:

```
#header{
    height:100px;
}

#nav{
    height:34px;
    position:relative;
}

.home{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background-image:url(http://gasworks.ravennainteractive.com/result/img/menu/single_line.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:34px;
    width:134px;
}

.home_hover{
    background-image:url(http://gasworks.ravennainteractive.com/result/img/menu/single_line_over.png);
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('home_hover').stop().animate({ height: '70px'},'slow');

    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: '34px'},'slow', function(){  
            $(this).removeClass('home_hover');
        })

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have to change the images a little but this works great.

Comment: Since you are most likely will have more than one tab, might I suggest just using one image? You won't need to add the CSS class at all and then can generalize the script to work with all the tabs.